# Get URL Parameter with PHP for Mysqli database search

Tags: php, ajax, url, parameters, mysqli

I'm trying to work out how to get the parameter from a URL with PHP. 
So my code starts with a bit of ajax firing the php and an alert with the response:

```
$.ajax({                                      
    url: 'blog/assets/php/load-blog.php',
    dataType: 'json',    
    success: function(data){
     alert(data);
    }
  });
```

Then I have my php:

```
<?php
  //==== CONNECTION VARIABLE
  $con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$database);


  //==== GET URL PARAMETER
  $urlParam =  $_GET["date"];


  //==== FETCH DATA
  $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE DATE = '$urlParam'");


  //==== CREATE ARRAY
  $blogArray = array();
  while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $blogArray[] = $row;
  }


  //==== ECHO AS JSON
  echo json_encode($blogArray);
?>
```

The URL would look something like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/blog/?date=2013-05-14
```

The issue in all of this is the URL parameter isn't being selected correctly but I don't know what I've done wrong.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use [parameterized queries](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) instead. And did you do an `echo $_GET["date"]`?

Comment: `$table` doesn't exist in your query

Comment: @antoox I removed the connection variables such as host, user, password and table form the code snippet for obvious security reasons. The issue I'm having is getting the URL parameter as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript

```
var date = '2013-05-14';

$.ajax({         
    type: "GET",                             
    url: 'blog/assets/php/load-blog.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { date: date }
    success: function(data){
     alert(data);
    }
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
//==== CONNECTION VARIABLE
$con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$database);


//==== GET URL PARAMETER
$urlParam =  $_GET["date"];

//==== PREPARED STATEMENT
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM __TABLE_NAME__ WHERE date = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $urlParam );
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name);

//==== CREATE ARRAY
$blogArray = array();

//==== FETCH DATA   
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $blogArray[] = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'name' => $name
    );
}

//==== CLOSE STATEMENT
$stmt->close();

//==== ECHO AS JSON
echo json_encode($blogArray);
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new with Ajax and PHP so don't know much about it. But wouldn't this method pull in all the database results then search with the Ajax? I just want the Mysqli query to deal with pulling the correct rows through.

Comment: Why POST? There is no data changed, so it is idempotent.

Comment: @Coop You need to send date with ajax firstly add an echo to see, are you sending date or not

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I was using post on ajax requests, probably not using post is better i deleted from answer

Comment: Why do I need to send the date with ajax? The date is in the URL parameter when the page loads. Can I not use $_GET["date"] in the PHP file to do that?

Comment: @Coop Think ajax like a new browser page when you make ajax query it will open -> http://site/blog/assets/php/load-blog.php, you don't send any addational data to php. You can get date parameters with javascript and add it to ajax query so php will get that parameter

Comment: @UtkuYıldırım Ah right I understand now! OK so I've got the date parameter sent to the PHP and that's working fine. I've tested it by sending it back as an echo. Now the last problem I have is that it's throwing a syntax error 'unexpected T_VARIABLE' which is breaking it. Any ideas what that is?

Comment: @UtkuYıldırım Not to worry I've found the syntax error, it's a missing bracket and semi-colon after the prepare statement. Now I'm getting a new error: 'Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()'   Any idea what that would be?

Comment: @UtkuYıldırım Really appreciate your help but now I'm getting another error: 'Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object' I feel like it's almost there but I don't know enough to solve these errors...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30223/discussion-between-utku-yildirim-and-coop)